# CSS : :not(s) selector as parent selector + :hover on classes misunderstanding

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply `:hover` only on desktop visitors of a webpage, and `:active` on the others. I'm setting the `mobile` class to the `body` element on the touchscreen devices version, and I put these lines in my css for the buttons in the document (elements with `btn` class) :

```
.btn {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    border-color: white;
}
:not(.mobile) .btn:hover {
    background: red;
    color: blue;
    border-color: black;
}
.mobile .btn:active {
    background: red;
    color: blue;
    border-color: black;
}
```

Here is an example of how this mobile webpage could be coded :

```
<html>
  <body class="mobile">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
    <div class="btn">button</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when browsing on the mobile page, the :hover pseudo-class is still selected even if the button is a child of the body with the `mobile` class ! Am I incorrectly understanding `:not(.mobile) .btn:hover` ?

I think it should select any immediate/distant element that has the `btn` class and is being hovered, and is a child of an element that doesn't have the `mobile` class...

I also tried others solutions like media queries, but I couln't get them to work as I expected.

The fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/162tn8ko/

Thank you for reading my bad english

Comment: why you bother with mobile since there is no hover on mobile?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I want to keep my code the same for both platforms, with the only difference being the `body` class. The goal of that css is to make hovering effects only happen on desktop platforms

Comment: and this is what I said, by default there is no hover on mobile, you cannot perform the hover action on mobile so no need to bother your self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you jhpratt, your answer helped me understand that the :not(s) was indeed applied on the `html` element. As Temani Afif guessed, in my code the `btn` is not a direct child of the body ; but here is what I was looking for :

```
body:not(.mobile) .btn:hover { ... }
```

complete solution : https://jsfiddle.net/162tn8ko/6/

Comment: Please refrain from posting an answer identical to one that I posted. That's what the "accept" checkmark is for.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, that selector is matching the `html` element, with the child of `div.btn`. To ensure it's a direct child, use `>`.

```css
.btn, .btn_noborder {
 background: blue;
 color: white;
 border-color: white;
}

/* note the following line */
:not(.mobile) > .btn:hover, :not(.mobile) > .btn_noborder:hover {
 background: red;
 color: blue;
 border-color: black;
}
.mobile .btn_noborder:active, .mobile .btn:active {
 background: red;
 color: blue;
 border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body class="mobile">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
    <div class="btn_noborder">button</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure his code is reduced and they won't be direct child in the real code

Comment: Sure, but the idea is the same. That's why media queries should be used, but that's not OP's question.